# Solve for third rank linear tensor equation $C_{[ij]k}U^jU^k=A_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors

Is there a way to solve a general tensor equation of the form, written in an arbitrary frame
\begin{equation}
C_{[ij]k}U^jU^k=A_i,
\end{equation}
for a tensor field $C$ of type $(0,3)$ (the square bracket denotes antisymmetrization), given the tangent vector field $U$ and one-form field $A$? That is, I hope to get an explicit form for the tensor $C$, and cast into a frame-independent form. In fact, the one-form field $A$ is some complex contractions of $U$ and other tensor fields, if helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not a chance. Just consider the degrees of freedom. In dimension $n$ the tensor $C$ has $n^3$ components and since you have only one free index on either side of your equation you could never hope to fix more than $n$ of them.

Maybe if $C$ and $A$ have a particular form then more might be possible.

Comment: In fact, a particular solution suffice for my purpose...

Comment: @Henry Oh, I see. What about $C_{ijk}=A_iA_jA_k(A_lU_l)^{−2}$?

Comment: Sorry but I don't recognize your computation. What is that of the inverse term?

Comment: @Henry Sorry, I meant take $A_iA_jA_k$ and divide it by the square of the scalar $A_lU^l$.

Comment: As a multiplication of function coefficient, isn't $A_iA_j$ symmetric, which leads to zero when antisymmetrization?

Comment: @Henry Oh shoot, I'm getting my square and round brackets mixed up. I don't know then.